# Does Google have an assembly reference or dll that I can add into my Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, google-chrome, .net-assembly

I searched and googled for this a bit, but don't seem to be able to find this...does anyone know if Google have this available for download for c# development? I don't want to use the stock webbrowser component that comes with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebKit .Net gives a library for WebKit written in C#.  Chrome uses WebKit.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/

Here is a related Stack Overflow thread -
[Google chrome control for .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534843/google-chrome-control-for-net)